# Reading xml document in xslt

Tags: xslt, xslt-2.0

I have a java method which return xml as string. I am calling this method from xslt and trying to process it as an xml document. The problem I am facing is that if you try to read that document into the varialble then xslt treated it as an string where as I want to use xpath queries to get some data .Here is my xslt

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xd="http://www.oxygenxml.com/ns/doc/xsl"
    xmlns:f="functions" xmlns:oracledb="java:com.application.dbmethods.OracleDB.TaxRef"
    exclude-result-prefixes="xs xd oracledb f" version="2.0"
    >
    <xsl:output indent="yes" method="xml"/>

 <xsl:template match="/">
   <oXrefs>
     <xsl:apply-templates />
   </oXrefs>
   <xsl:variable name="doc">
     <xsl:sequence select="oracledb:getMetaDataSP()"/>
   </xsl:variable>

   <xsl:message> 
     <xsl:value-of select="$doc/abbrev"></xsl:value-of>
   </xsl:message>

 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

if I use

```
     <xsl:value-of select="$doc"></xsl:value-of>
```

then I am getting string output but I need to access the nodes of that document using xpath like $doc/abbrev and so on. Any help will be appreciated.  I am using saxon xslt processor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used saxon:parse to fix it.

```
    <xsl:variable name="doc">
     <xsl:sequence select="saxon:parse(oracledb:getMetaDataSP())"/>
   </xsl:variable>
```